# xeyes in each of my Ubuntu 14.04 install is missing the title bar

Tags: titlebar

I often bring up xeyes to test X11 display, especially when checking out my remote X sessions.  However, without a title bar, it's not easy to close.  I have to kill the window instead.

Does anyone know how to bring the title bar back to xeyes?

---

Some clarifications.  There are reasons that I use the title bar in windows which includes **grabbing** resource for **moving** (alt mouse cursor fails in a virtual machine).  I at times send the xeyes to my real machine as an easy visual that the remote machine is alive.  The missing title bar/boards makes it impossible (for me) to re-size it.  When there were borders I use to make it extremely small, make it **always on top**, and move it to a convenient location away from my other work.  I also miss being able to put it **available on all workspaces**.

I guess if I ask a question for each of the needs I could probably get most of the things done with some type of workaround.  However, I find the title bar a convenient tool for quickly and conveniently working with a window.  My "real" question is, does anyone know of a way to invoke the title bar in xeyes.

Answer (score 0):

Is a right-click on the launcher not an option? After starting xeyes it also brings up that icon on the launcher. You can right-click on it and choose Quit.

Comment: Thanks for the input and workaround.  I should have mentioned that I had tried to use right clicking to bring up the title bar and a little more details of the need of the title bar.  When doing some of my remote work I often do it in a virtual machine.  Without a title bar, I don't know how to move the xeyes on a virtual machine.  On my real machine I can hold the alt button and move it with the mouse.  But this doesn't work on a virtual machine.  Since you mention work around, are you saying it isn't possible to have a title bar?